# How to fit a power curve for a glm with simr

Tags: nonparametric, poisson-distribution, sample-size, simulation, glmm

My response variable is counts of turtles at sea surface per aerial survey (possible values: 0,1,2) and I use a Poisson distribution for it (since my data are not overdispersed neither zero inflated). I sampled two different areas for a certain period of time. I built several glmm in order to find out if I could discriminate a difference between these areas, taking into account temporal random factors. In all the models I built I found almost zero variance due to the random factors and an effect of my variable Area (categorical dicotomic variable) = 0.7 almost always significant. I am interested in performing a power analysis in order to understand how much I can trust in that result and how much I should sample next years in order to have that effect with a power of 80% at least. I tried with SIMR package, starting with a model y ~ Area (1|day), but the effect of the random factor is so small that the function powerSim can't work with it. So, I just tried to make a power analysis for y ~ Area. The function powerSim gave me a value for the power, so I was interested in going on with a power Curve but I cannot find the way to extend my model properly: I would just like to extend the sample size itself (mine is nrow=128), by typing for exemple extend(model, within= "Area", n = 300). The function does extends the model someway but I cannot understand how: I get nrows = 484, while according to me I shoud just get nrows = 300 (that's what I am interested in...).
Hope someone can help me with this.
Sorry for my bad explanation I am completely new in this blog and in R in general!

Comment: "*survey (possible values: 0,1,2)*" -- why would a value like say 3 not be *possible*?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica sorry I explained myself bad: I was referring to the data I already collected and that I am using for the models and the power analysis ecc.. in my dataset the count of turtles per statistical unit (which is one flight of the drone over a defined sea area) ranges between 0 and 2.